# Rails Streamio FFMPEG taking a screenshot of the movie and upload with carrierwave

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, ffmpeg

I have got a Form where I can upload a movie. Its uploaded with carrierwave.

In this process I want to Make a screenshot of the movie while uploading.

How can I do this with  Streamio FFMPEG.

My code Looks like this at the moment.

```
#Laedt ein Video hoch
def uploadMovie
  @channels = Channel.all
  @vid = Movie.new(movies_params)

  @channel = Channel.find(params[:channel_id])
  @vid.channel = @channel

  if @vid.save
    flash[:notice] = t("flash.saved")
    render :add
  else
    render :add
  end
end
```

Do I have to do this in controller method or in the carrierwave uplaoder?

Update: I tried it this way:

```
if @vid.save
  flash[:notice] = t("flash.saved")
  movieFile = FFMPEG::Movie.new(@vid.video.to_s)
  screenshot = movieFile.screenshot("uploads/screenshot", :seek_time => 10)
  render :add
else
```

But then I got tis error:

```
s3.amazonaws.com/uploads/movie/video/6/2016-04-24_16.26.10.mp4' does not exist
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution is carrierwave thumbnailer gem

```
gem 'carrierwave-video-thumbnailer'
```

https://github.com/evrone/carrierwave-video-thumbnailer